# Using local GEOJson with OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

I am a relative beginner to using OpenLayers so I was playing around with some of the examples given on the OpenLayers website. When trying the image-vector-layer example, I had a problem where it would work fine with a json online, but when using a local geojson file the response under the networks section for the geojson file would be an html instead, giving the error "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0". Attached is my javascript below, the error is occurring at the "url: data/countries.geojson". Is there any way I can  use a local file instead of an online link? Thank you!

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import VectorImageLayer from 'ol/layer/VectorImage';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import View from 'ol/View';
import {Fill, Stroke, Style} from 'ol/style';

const style = new Style({
  fill: new Fill({
    color: '#eeeeee',
  }),
});

const vectorLayer = new VectorImageLayer({
  background: 'lightblue',
  imageRatio: 2,
  source: new VectorSource({
    url: 'data/countries.geojson',
    format: new GeoJSON(),
  }),
  style: function (feature) {
    const color = feature.get('COLOR') || '#eeeeee';
    style.getFill().setColor(color);
    return style;
  },
});

const map = new Map({
  layers: [vectorLayer],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 1,
  }),
});

const featureOverlay = new VectorLayer({
  source: new VectorSource(),
  map: map,
  style: new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)',
      width: 2,
    }),
  }),
});

let highlight;
const displayFeatureInfo = function (pixel) {
  const feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function (feature) {
    return feature;
  });

  const info = document.getElementById('info');
  if (feature) {
    info.innerHTML = feature.get('ECO_NAME') || '&nbsp;';
  } else {
    info.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
  }

  if (feature !== highlight) {
    if (highlight) {
      featureOverlay.getSource().removeFeature(highlight);
    }
    if (feature) {
      featureOverlay.getSource().addFeature(feature);
    }
    highlight = feature;
  }
};

map.on('pointermove', function (evt) {
  if (evt.dragging) {
    return;
  }
  const pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
  displayFeatureInfo(pixel);
});

map.on('click', function (evt) {
  displayFeatureInfo(evt.pixel);
});
```

Comment: If you are using IIS localhost you need to add `.geojson` extension to the server MIME types as `application/json`.  Alternatively name your file with a `.json` extension.

Comment: I changed it to a .json extension but I still have the same problem!

Comment: I am also not using IIS, I am using a localhost so I cannot do the first option either.

Comment: What server are you using on localhost?  You still need to support the `.geojson` MIME type.

Comment: The posted code works for me (admittedly on a website, not localhost, and using the legacy build/syntax: [working map](http://www.geocodezip.com/OL_6.14.1_localGeoJson_20220620.html)).  You are trying to load countries.json from 2 different location (`data/countries.geojson` and `countries.geojson`), do you really have that file in both locations?  I also modified your code to read the file that exists on my server.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to edit out the first part where I was just playing around with the code, I've removed it now. The correct location is in data/countries.geojson. I'm sorry I'm rather new to web development, if I'm using the npm developmental server as on the OpenLayers tutorial how would I change the MIME type support?

Comment: It is also possible to fetch the file using `axios.get('/data/countries.json')`, but I've done it for JSON files.